# AJAX Post - Passing Variables - What am I not Seeing

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net

I'm getting the follow error:

```
"Message":"No parameterless constructor defined for type of \u0027System.String\u0027.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertDictionaryToObject(IDictionary`2 dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException"}
```

I'd assuming this is happening because I'm not passing something from my ajax post correctly but I can't see it :(.  If I don't pass any parameters, and I remove the parameters from the web method it works.  However, with them, it doesn't.  Also, if I try to pass a JSON object it doesn't work either.  I posted that code at the bottom.  If someone can help me out I'd appreciate it!  Thanks.

#### AJAX

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'Process.aspx/updateAProcess',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'ProcessID': ProcessID, 'ProcessDescription': ProcessDescription, 'ProcessName': ProcessName }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Winner!");
                    }
                });
```

#### Web Method

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
Public Shared Function updateAProcess(ByVal ProcessID As String, ByVal ProcessDescription As String, ByVal ProcessName As String)
    Dim pBSL As New ProcessBSL
    pBSL.ProcessUpdate(ProcessID, ProcessDescription, ProcessName)
    Return Nothing


End Function
```

#### Using JSON

Here's my data call:
`data: JSON.stringify({ updateProcess: updateProcess }),`

Here's where I create the updateProcess:

```
                var updateProcess = new Object();
                updateProcess.ProcessName = $("#ProcessNameChange").val();
                updateProcess.ProcessDescription = $("#ProcessDescChange").val();
                updateProcess.ProcessID = $(this).closest("tr").children()[4];
```

It results in  this error:
`{"Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027ProcessID\u0027.","StackTrace"`

On the back end, I have an object called a ProcessBO, which has a dozen attributes and my webmethod is:

```
    Public Shared Function update(ByVal updateProcess As ProcessBO)
    Dim pBSL As New ProcessBSL
    pBSL.ProcessUpdate(updateProcess.ProcessID, updateProcess.ProcessDescription, updateProcess.ProcessName)
    Return Nothing
```

Comment: Try with `data: { 'ProcessID': ProcessID, 'ProcessDescription': ProcessDescription, 'ProcessName': ProcessName },`

Comment: To do this approach (`data: JSON.stringify({ updateProcess: updateProcess })`), you would need a corresponding class (`UpdateProcess`) on the server side that had matching property names of `ProcessName`, `ProcessDescription` and `ProcessID`. If you had that class on the server-side then you could change the arguments of your ASP.NET AJAX Page Method to `updateAProcess(ByVal _updateProcess As UpdateProcess)`, then you could dereference the object to get the property values out. When the property names match the JSON passed in, then it is automatically deserialized for you.

Comment: @tymeJV, that generates this error: "Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: ProcessID."

Comment: @KarlAnderson I have a coresponding class that is update process.  I'll update my question with more details regarding that.

Comment: Stupid ASP.NET, try `data: '{ ProcessID: "' + ProcessID + '", ProcessDescription: "' + ProcessDescription + '", ProcessName: "' + ProcessName + '"  }',`

Answer (score 2):

The error message occurs because an exception is occurring when ASP.Net is trying to decode the parameters. Somehow or another, its internal code ends up trying to deserialize an Exception.

The root of the problem is that you are passing string parameters as straight text instead of encapsulating them in quotes. For example, if ProcessID = "1", ProcessDescription = "2" and ProcessName = "3", your params will look like:

```
{ 'ProcessID': 1, 'ProcessDescription': 2, 'ProcessName': 3 }
```

but they should look like

```
{ 'ProcessID': '1', 'ProcessDescription': '2', 'ProcessName': '3' }
```

I have found that the easiest and safest way to accomplish this is to actually create a js class with the corresponding parameters, populate it with the data, and pass this class to stringify:

```
var params = new Object();
params.ProcessID = ProcessID;
params.ProcessDescription = ProcessDescription;
params.ProcessName = ProcessName;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Process.aspx/updateAProcess',
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
...
```